# #1066 - Not unique table/alias: error while running an command

Tags: java, mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Ihave created 2foreign keys customer id  and now iam tryin to run this command to getan output but get this error#1066 - Not unique table/alias:`enter code here`
{
SELECT `productid` FROM `javabase`.`sales`
JOIN `sales` on `sales`.`customerid`=`customer`.`customerid`
where `customer`.`customername`=`Babu`;
}

Comment: Should Join Sales be Join Customer?

Comment: yes i gave sales instead of customer thanks its fixed

Answer (score 0):

You have to use at least one alias when you join a table to itself. So instead of `FROM sales JOIN sales` it would be `FROM sales S1 JOIN sales S2`